# Python lambda used as an argument, calling other arguments from parent function

Tags: python, lambda, arguments

I'm new to programming and am having a little trouble understanding the lambda function in Python. I understand why it's used and its effectiveness. Just having trouble learning to apply it. I've read a guide and watched a lecture on using lambda as an argument. I've tried using the map function. Not sure if that's the correct approach, but this is my broken code in its most basic form:

```
def Coord(x, y, z=lambda: z*2 if z < x or z < y else z)):
    print(z)
Coord(10,20,30) 
Coord(10,20,12) 
Coord(10,20,8)
```

Needs to return 30, 24, and 32, respectively.
Working code without using lambda:

```
def Coord(x, y, z):
    while z < x or z < y:
        z*=2
print(z)
```

Comment: If you are new to programming you might want to do something a little simpler with lambdas first and understand how they work, as it stands your code is not remotely near working.

Comment: _"I've read a guide and watched a lecture on using lambda as an argument"_. Got links?

Comment: Yes
The guide is https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/lambda_tutorial/
and the last ~5 minutes here
http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/unit-1/lecture-9-memory-and-search-methods/

Comment: `z` is a function, so you probably don't want to print it, but rather its return value when called: `print(z())`. However, `z` in the body of the function will also refer to the argument passed to `Coord` (that is, to itself), so it's not clear where the actual value you want is coming from.

Comment: There's also an extra ) or something.

Comment: @user2145382 Yeah I had it with my fail map methods in there before I edited it.

Comment: lambdas generally do not go on the `def` line of another function. It's not illegal, but for the most part you will not need to do it. I think you may have misunderstood the `command=lambda:...` examples in that blog post.

Comment: Please clarify the problem you're trying to solve.  First of all, why are you insisting on using a lambda function as a default parameter value?  This doesn't match your input.  Also, please provide a good description of the needed output.  Most of all, how do you get output of 32 for an input of 8?  Your apparent algorithm does no more than multiply it by 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use other parameters from the Coord function in your default parameter definition for z (which is a lambda function in your case).

You may want to do something like this:

```
def Coord(x, y, w, z=lambda a,b,c: c*2 if c < a or c < b else c):
    print(z(x,y,w))
```

or

```
def Coord(x, y, w):
    z=lambda: w*2 if w < x or w < y else w
    print(z())
```

Both definitions are equivalent when evaluating them with 3 arguments, and they result in:

```
>>> Coord(10,20,30)
30
>>> Coord(10,20,12)
24
>>> Coord(10,20,8)
16
```

Comment: It might be worth noting that, in this context, a function with a descriptive name probably makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks, your answer clarified a lot for me!